# codeigniter looping data in foreach using for

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to looping data in foreach using for in html so i don't want to type `<input type>` one by one.

Edit :

Sorry I did not inform you completely,so in my database i have columns like this.

```
//my database

team_id
//Participants 1
name_1
phone_1
email_1
//Participants 2
name_2
phone_2
email_2
//Participants 3
name_3
phone_3
email_3

//view
//$data is from my controller
<?php foreach($data as $rowdata) {   
//1
$name_1=$rowdata->name_1;
$phone_1=$rowdata->phone_1;
$email_1=$rowdata->email_;
//2
$name_2=$rowdata->name_2;
$phone_2=$rowdata->phone_2;
$email_2=$rowdata->email_2;
//3
$name_3=$rowdata->name_3;
$phone_3=$rowdata->phone_3;
$email_3=$rowdata->email_3;
}?>

<?php for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){ ?>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?php echo $name_$i ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><?php echo $phone_$i ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?php echo $email_$i ?></td>
</tr>
```

so, how i can looping like that using for,Thanks

Comment: use array of objects. put all of your data in one array

Comment: Is $data a result from a query to your database?

Comment: yup, $data is from controllers

Answer (score 3):

In your comments, you answered that `$data` is the result from your db.

I assume that your db has 3 columns `Name`, `Phone` and `Email` and NOT `Name_1`, `Name_2`, `Phone_1` etc...

Code:

```
<?php foreach($data as $rowdata) { ?>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?= $rowdata['name'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><?= $rowdata['phone'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?= $rowdata['email'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your second assumption is almost right,my db has columns like this `name_1`,`phone_1`,`email_1`,`name_2`,`phone_2`,`email_2`,etc

Comment: and how many columns you have with that logic (_1, _2, _3 etc..)?

Answer (score 1):

$data is an array of objects, so don't need to use 2 loops for getting and print data.You can do this in one loop.

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($data as $rowdata) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><?= $rowdata->name ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td><?= $rowdata->phone ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><?= $rowdata->email ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know syntax is ok but logic is below

```
<table>
    <?php 
        $i=1;
        foreach($data as $rowdata) { 
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><?= $rowdata->name.'_'.$i; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td><?= $rowdata->phone.'_'.$i; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><?= $rowdata->email.'_'.$i; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; }?>
</table>
```